# How to handle NULL Z/M values in Postgis?

Tags: postgis

Using `ST_SetPoint` on a line with a `NaN` Z fails

```
select st_setpoint(
st_makeline(ARRAY[ST_MakePoint(1,2,'Nan'), ST_MakePoint(3,4,10), ST_MakePoint(5,6, 20)]),
2, ST_MakePoint(5,6, 'Nan'))
```

Fails with `Geometry contains invalid coordinates`

Tested with docker images (postgis/postgis), this fails in Postgis 3.3 and 3.4 but works in 3.1 and 3.2.

From one answer on osgeo's [ticket](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/5610#ticket), float handling might have changed in 3.2.

While I understand this can be an issue to do this, what is the suggested approach to handle null Z/M values in lines or polygons?

Comment: Works for me with PostGIS version 3.1, PostgreSQL version 12.3. I guess that the PostGIS version is what matters.

Comment: Thanks, I update the questions with more precise context

Comment: I also created a bug report in case: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/5610#ticket